Can't find `min_granularity_ns`(sched) on Ubuntu 24.04
In previous LTS of Ubuntu with the newer version of Linux kernel /proc/sys/kernel/sched_min_granularity_ns has been moved to /sys/kernel/debug/sched/min_granularity_ns. In Ubuntu 24.04, this parameter/file vanished from //sys/kernel/debug/sched.
Does anyone know where it is located now (i.e. in Ubuntu 24.04) or whether it was replaced with something else?

Try reading the change logs with apt-get changelog [packagename] or search for it with sudo find /sys/kernel -name min_granularity_ns.

Since no answer was given, I had to dig for it myself and it took a while.
Ubuntu 24.04 was released with Kernel version 6.8. Apparently, the Kernel 6.6 made a leap and one of the major changes was moving from CFS scheduler to EEVDF scheduler (see here). As part of this change the contents of /sys/kernel/debug/sched underwent some changes. One of this changes was the replacement of min_granularity_ns with base_slice_ns (see here).
Please note that some other changes have been made to this set of controls. For instance, wakeup_granularity_ns is not used in EEVDF and thus was omitted, and a new control preempt has been added that allows finetuning of the scheduler preemption.
